# No route found for PUT /api/users/id

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to update a record in my mysql database by calling the put method from my sencha touch 2 frontend. I'm calling this url /api/users/id but I keep getting a Symfony error:

```
No route found for "PUT /api/users/1
```

This is what I have in my routing.yml file

```
users:
    resource: "Acme\MainBundle\Controller\UsersController"
    prefix:   /api
    type:     rest
```

Also, I have the putUsersAction setup in my User**s**Controller

```
public function putUsersAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $values['birthdate'] = $request->get('birthdate');
    $values['clubid'] = $request->get('clubid');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:User')
        ->find($id);

    $club = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:Club')
        ->find($values['clubid']);

    $user->setBirthdate($values['birthdate']);
    $user->addClub($club);

    $em->flush();

    $view = View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData($user);

    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

Why is Symfony telling me there's no PUT /api/users/id route?

EDIT 1: router:debug output

```
[router] Current routes
Name                     Method Pattern
_wdt                     ANY    /_wdt/{token}
_profiler_search         ANY    /_profiler/search
_profiler_purge          ANY    /_profiler/purge
_profiler_info           ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
_profiler_import         ANY    /_profiler/import
_profiler_export         ANY    /_profiler/export/{token}.txt
_profiler_phpinfo        ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
_profiler_search_results ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
_profiler                ANY    /_profiler/{token}
_profiler_redirect       ANY    /_profiler/
_configurator_home       ANY    /_configurator/
_configurator_step       ANY    /_configurator/step/{index}
_configurator_final      ANY    /_configurator/final
get_users                GET    /api/users.{_format}
post_users               POST   /api/users.{_format}
get_clubs                GET    /api/clubs.{_format}
post_clubs               POST   /api/clubs.{_format}
put_users                PUT    /api/users.{_format}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you should debug your routing and see if the route is being registered correctly. Your posted routing snipped lacks correct intendation. It should read:

```
user:
    resource: "Acme\MainBundle\Controller\UserController"
    prefix:   /api
    type:     rest
```

Afterwards you can debug your routing with the console command:

```
php app/console router:debug
```

Furthermore you can use grep ( Unix ) or findstr ( Windows ) to search the output for your route:

```
php app/console router:debug | grep /api
```

or

```
php app/console router:debug | findstr /api
```

Next make sure for the **automatic routing** of FOSRestBundle to work as expected to name your controller User**s**Controller and the file User**s**Controller.php.

See: [FOSRestBundle Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition)

Please note that you have forgotten to call persist($user) before flushing and that you cannot call flush on your User entity but on your EntityManager. See my example below.

You can slim down your controller a lot by using DependencyInjection , the symfony2 **ParamConverter**, [implicit resource name definition](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition) and the **@View** Annotation provided by the FOSRestBundle.

Your Controller would then read something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Acme\MainBundle\Entity\User;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;

/**
 * @DI\Service
 */
class UserController
{

    /** @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager") */
    private $em;

    // ...

    /**
     * @View()
     */
    public function putAction(User $user, Request $request)
    {

        $club = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:Club')
            ->findOneById($request->get('clubid'));

        $user
            ->setBirthdate($request->get('birthdate')
            ->addClub($club);

        // you should add some validation here 

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $user;
   }

   // ...
}
```

Explanations:

I have used the JMSDiExtraBundle's annotations. You need this bundle to make them work.

Otherwise you should declare your controller as a service and inject the EntityManager manually ( for example in your bundle's Resources/config/services.xml ) in the service container.

Declare your controller as Service with @DI\Service annotation.

Inject your EntityManager here to be be able to access it throughout the class with $this->em with the @DI\Inject annotation.

Use FOSRest's @View annotation.
Don't forget to set sensio_framework_extra.view: { annotations: false } before using this if you have the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle's in your application.

Make sure you have return $this; at the end of your User entity's setBirthdate(...) and addClub(...) functions.

Please not that i have used [JMSDiExtraBundle's property injection][3] in the example.
The bundle has to be installed in order to be used.

You might be able to slim down the controller further by using the NoxLogicMultiParamBundle.

**I cannot post more than 2 links because im new over here...**

- please look for the following resources on google:
- NoxLogicMultiParamBundle
- FOSRestBundle documentation
- JMSDiExtraBundle documentation

Comment: thx for your reply. The markup for the routing is correct in the app. Just had the indent messed up here. :) I have a working 'postUsersAction' already so I think the link between route and controller is correct. I have updated my question with the route:debug as I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Thx for all the extra tips btw

Comment: I just found out why it wasn't working. putUsersAction should be putUserAction (so singular :))

Comment: Thanks. Running the command: php app/console router:debug | grep /api I found that the route name that wasn't working was pointed to another Controller. Which means I had two routes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
user:
    pattern:   /api/user/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeMainBundle:User:putUsers, id: 1 }
```

or you could use the FQCN:

```
defaults:  { _controller: Acme\MainBundle\Controller\UserController::putUsersAction, id: 1 }
```

and to match only PUT request use the below code, although some browsers don't support PUT and DELETE see [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html)

```
user:
    pattern:   /api/user/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: Acme\MainBundle\Controller\UserController::putUsers, id: 1 }
    requirements:
        _method:  PUT
```

...and of course to see all of your routes, run this from your project folder:

```
php app/console router:debug
```